# Sharepoint 2016 installation fails during prerequisite installation

Tags: app-fabric

I am trying to install sharepoint server 2016 on a 64-bit Windows 10 server OS but the installation fails during prerequisite installation.

The error is due to the following line:
Cumulative Update Package 7 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB3092423): installation error

I tried separate install of CU7 update for AppFabric 11 and it failed too.
The log file of the separate install:

> [04/14/18 14:55:53] Performing install.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:53] At least one of the product packages has been detected.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:53] preReqUpdateDisplayName is :
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Operation succeeded.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Package AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server is installed.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Package code is {96E70525-4CD1-4920-9C0B-91055C79A962}.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Executing preinstall custom actions. 2 actions to execute.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Starting process "C:\Windows\system32..\sysnative\cmd.exe" /c regedit /e /s "C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\AF_Cache.reg" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0  ...
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Operation failed. Error code is 6.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Deleting file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers Updates\Updates\Uninstall3092423\EBizTemp.txt ...
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] Operation succeeded.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] The custom action returned 6.
>
> [04/14/18 14:55:58] One of the custom actions failed. The installation cannot continue. See log for details.

I think the error code 6 is the windows system error code "The Handle is invalid" but I'm not sure how to resolve it.
I tried to uninstall and install the AppFabric for Windows Server completely but the issue persists.
Could you please provide some solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi try to enable internet on server and install pre-rquisites

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2016 isn't supported on Windows 10. You need to use a supported version of Windows Server.